# How to Detect If JS is Running in Website Builder?

Tags: javascript

I want to display forums inside websites where my javascript (and HTML and CSS) is embedded, but if the javascript is running inside a website builder, I just want to have some text telling the user their forums are installed here (in the embedded DIV) and not try to display any forums. My only idea is to look at the URL and if I see a known website builder, then run the website builder code, but I would need a large list of all website builder URLs. Does anyone have such a list or is there a better solution? My current code looks like this:

```
var hostURL = window.location.href;
if (hostURL == "about:srcdoc") hostURL = window.parent.location.href;
if (hostURL.indexOf("websites.godaddy.com") > -1 ||                 // godaddy  
    hostURL.indexOf(".preview.editmysite.com") > -1)    {           // weebly
        displayWebsiteBuilderInfo();
        return;
}
```

Comment: Can you define precisely what is a "website builder"? If so, you might use these criteria for detection.

Comment: Website builders like Wix and Squarespace.

Comment: If you can only list them by example, your code won't be able to approach this any differently.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, but I'm not sure if it's a good solution (and it's not a solution for the original question):

In the PHP code that handles the request to get the forums data I read the content at the referer URL (comes from the client - window.location.href) to see if the javascript is there. If it's not there, assume the request came from a website builder. Then if isWebsiteBuilder is true back at the client, call displayWebsiteBuilderInfo();

Here's the PHP code:

```
$siteContent = @file_get_contents($referer);
$siteContent = htmlspecialchars_decode($siteContent);
$idx = strpos($siteContent, "<script async src=\"https://www.bubblecritic.com/js/embed/the_js.js\"></script>");
if ($idx === false) $isWebsiteBuilder = true;
```